# Jquery noConflict Syntax advise

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please let me know how to write Jquery noConflict for the below javascript? Anyone kindly advise me the syntax for this one?

```
function openSearch() {
      $("#myOverlay").fadeIn(); // "500" is not required. "400" is the default value
  }

  function closeSearch() {
      $("#myOverlay").fadeOut();  // "500" is not required. ""400 is the default value
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unnamed function wrapper to pass jQuery as parameter.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
(function($){

  $("#myOverlay").fadeIn(); // "500" is not required. "400" is the default 
  $("#myOverlay").fadeOut();  // "500" is not required. ""400 is the default 

})(jQuery)
```

Comment: Of course you can put your functions inside unamed immediately execuded js wrapper function, but they no longer will be attached to window object. To have them work in global scope you need to assing them to window object like:

`window.openSearch = function(){}`